# Android check internet connection Toast displaying no internet

Tags: android, webview, timer, toast, android-internet

Hello I have a small application which simply displays a webview when it has an internet connection but it doesn't have an internet connection I want it to display a toast. Currently when I run the application it will display a toast message saying "No internet connection" even though there is an internet connection and the webview will open to is designated website. I would only expect to see this toast message if there is no internet. I have included my code below could tell me what I have done wrong, I'm expecting its only something minor.

```
public class Facebook extends Fragment {

WebView facebookWebiew;

public Facebook() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);

    View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);

    try{

        facebookWebiew = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.facebookWebview);
        facebookWebiew.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = facebookWebiew.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        facebookWebiew.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



        URL url = new URL("www.google.co.uk");
        executeReq(url);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Webpage is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (Exception e){


        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Webpage is  not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }




    return v;


}


private void executeReq(URL urlObject)throws IOException{

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObject.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000); // milliseconds
    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000); // milliseconds
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);

    conn.connect();
    InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
    Log.d("Response", response.toString());


}


}
```

### Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

-- Also using permission Access network

Print Trace

```
 I/System.out: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
 I/System.out:     at   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
 I/System.out:     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
 I/System.out:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
 I/System.out:     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
 I/System.out:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
 I/System.out:at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
 I/System.out:at SocialMedia.Facebook.executeReq(Facebook.java:88)
 I/System.out:at SocialMedia.Facebook.onCreateView(Facebook.java:58)
 I/System.out:at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
 I/System.out:at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
 I/System.out:at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
 I/System.out:at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
 I/System.out:at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
 I/System.out:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
 I/System.out:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 I/System.out:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 I/System.out:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
I/System.out:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
I/System.out:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
I/System.out:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
I/System.out:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
I/System.out:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: which is the Exception that is triggered?

Comment: }catch (Exception e){


        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Webpage is  not working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

Comment: Put `e.printStackTrace()` and post the logcat output here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use getcontext() here, use getapplicationcontext() or getbasecontext()

```
Toast.maketext(getApplicationContext()," web page not working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: changed it to getActivity().getApplicationContext() because I'm on a fragment, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Webpage is working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Or else create a Context in your fragment and pass it to Toast.

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` is triggered when you execute network requests on the main UI thread. To figure out the issue you have to use an `AsyncTask` and place the `executeReq` code inside its `doInBackground` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion sadly still have the problem :D

Comment: are you still getting `java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found` as Exception in the stack trace?

Comment: After changing it to your suggestion it has disappeared

Comment: ok but are you getting the right toast message "Webpage is working" or a new different Exception?

Comment: still getting "Webpage is not working" when internet is turned on

Comment: Thank you lino, could you show me the little bits of code I need to change as this is my first time with networks on an application.

Comment: public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
        

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            return null;
        }
    }

Comment: Where do I take it from here?

Comment: Hi Lino i'm still confused